# Указатель this c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, классы, visual-c++, указатели

Добрый вечер. У меня такой вопрос, недавно лазил в инете и наткнулся на такой код: `return*this*Fraction(fra.fenm, fra.fenzi);` где fenm-числитель, а fenzi-знаменатель. Хотелось бы узнать, что означает такая запись `*this*`. Это указатель на класс или конструктор? Вот тот самы код. Если что есть ссылка [ссылка на код](http://www.programering.com/a/MzNxMTNwATU.html)

Заранее спасибо.

```
Fraction::Fraction(int zi,int mu):fenzi(zi),fenmu(mu){
    if(mu==0){
        cout<<"The denominator can not be 0!"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Fraction &fra){
    if(fra.fenmu<0)
        out<<"(-"<<fra.fenzi<<"/"<<-fra.fenmu<<")";        //Negative   scores
    else if(fra.fenzi<0)
        out<<"(-"<<-fra.fenzi<<"/"<<fra.fenmu<<")";
    else if(fra.fenmu==1)
        out<<fra.fenzi;                                    //Integer show
    else
        out<<fra.fenzi<<"/"<<fra.fenmu;                    //Positive scores
    return out;
}
istream& operator>>(istream& in, Fraction& fra){
    int mu,zi;
    cout<<"Please enter the denominator and numerator"<<endl;
    in>>mu>>zi;
    fra.setValue(mu,zi);
    return in;
}
void Fraction::setValue(int mu,int zi){
    fenmu=mu;
    fenzi=zi;
}
Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction &fra)const{
    int a=fenzi,b=fenmu;    //▲▲▲A key▲▲▲
    //Be sure to use the const, not because it will make the last operational data assigned to the next operation in l-value
    //Because the const function cannot change the class of internal variables, so use avatars, if here with friend heavy load
    //It can effectively avoid this problem, because the friend overloaded operators have two reference parameters
    a=fra.fenmu*fenzi+fra.fenzi*fenmu;
    b*=fra.fenmu;
    int g=GreatestCommonDivisor(a,b);
    if (g!=1)
    {
        a/=g;
        b/=g;
    }
    return Fraction(a,b);
}
Fraction Fraction::operator-(const Fraction &fra)const{
    int a=fenzi,b=fenmu;
    a=fra.fenmu*fenzi-fra.fenzi*fenmu;
    b*=fra.fenmu;
    int g=GreatestCommonDivisor(a,b);
    if (g!=1)
    {
        a/=g;
        b/=g;
    }
    return Fraction(a,b);
}
Fraction Fraction::operator*(const Fraction &fra)const{
    int a=fenzi,b=fenmu;
    a*=fra.fenzi;
    b*=fra.fenmu;
    int g=GreatestCommonDivisor(a,b);
    if (g!=1)
    {
        a/=g;
        b/=g;
    }
    return Fraction(a,b);
}
Fraction Fraction::operator/(const Fraction &fra)const{
    return *this*Fraction(fra.fenmu,fra.fenzi);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Автор кода явно экономил на тексте. `*this` - это просто разыменование указателя, дающее ссылку `const Fraction &` на данный экземпляр класса, а последующий `*` - это перегруженный оператор умножения. Оператор деления реализован как умножение на обратную величину. Если добавить скобочек и пробелов, то должно получатся нагляднее:

```
return((*this) * Fraction(fra.fenmu, fra.fenzi));
```

также перегруженный оператор умножения можно вызвать как функцию:

```
return(operator *(Fraction(fra.fenmu, fra.fenzi)));
```

или с явным `this`:

```
return(this->operator *(Fraction(fra.fenmu, fra.fenzi)));
```

Приведенные три варианта делают одно и то же.

Comment: Аааа понял, спасибо

Comment: @Lado, тогда пометьте ответ как правильный